# Windows Service setup project - run service as administrator

Tags: windows, service, installation, admin

I've got a setup project for a Windows Service (.net 3.5, visual studio 2008).

The Windows Service needs to be run under the Administrator account, does anyone know how I can get the Setup Project to set the "user to log on as" setting for the windows service as part of the setup process?

At the moment I have to manually right click on the service and set it to log on as the administrator everytime I update the service.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to add a new **ServiceProcessInstaller** in the **InitializeComponent()** method of your installer.  This class will allow you to set account type, username, and password that you want the service to run as. For example:

```
this.Installers.Add(
        new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller()
            {
                Account = ServiceAccount.User,
                Username = @"domain\username",
                Password = "password"
            });
```

If you don't want to hardcode a password into your setup project, then leave it blank and a popup dialog should appear asking for this during install.

Comment: thanks! - do you know how to get the service to auto-start as well?

Comment: No sorry, never had to do that before.  I'd add it as another question if I was you.

Comment: PrinterMonitorServiceInstaller.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Automatic this will do this

Comment: ServiceInstaller's StartType Property has options for service as "Automatic","Manual" and "Disabled"..this can be used to set service start mode.In my project i set it to automatic ,after installation in services list my service start property is automatic but not started immidiately after setup...how to also run service after setup??